# How to open an accordion via an anchor and set an active-state

Tags: jquery, anchor, accordion

I'm not very familiar with jquery. But nevertheless I want to realize an accordion with the following functionality:
The accordion should open in 2 ways.
1) by clicking on an external navigation on the same page.
2) by clicking on the accordions headline
Additionally i would like to have an active-state once on the navigation below and second on the li-Tag from the accordion.

My Navigation-structure:

```
<a href="#a" class="opener" data-panel="0">A</a>
<a href="#b" class="opener" data-panel="1">B</a>
<a href="#c" class="opener" data-panel="2">C</a>
```

My Accordion-structure:

```
<li id='a'>
    <h2><Headline</h2>
    <ul class='inner'>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Could you folks give me an advice, how to reach this?
Many thanks!!!

Comment: So, what have you tried to solve this ? with the code you shared i cannot see any ' accordion' type of actions happening

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have the same function called on both of the events you want the accordion opened. Just tie the "click" event in both cases to the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

*Use this code for accordian with jquery...*

> add those links

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

> add this script in head

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  } );
  </script>
```

> add this code in html

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
   Option 1
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Option 2
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Option 3
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok lucky - many thanks. that works so far!
And how do i get the anchor to work? 
A click on the anchor should bring me to the accordion-section and open it automatically. Any ideas?

Comment: <a href="#accordion" id="accordion" class="btn btn-primary">Option 1</a> maybe try this one